# Remove all query strings from requests for particular page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, query-string

I have a flex application that for some reason I do not know why, when you are using google chrome and access the page with any query strings in the URL the applications behaves unexpectedly.

The page does not need query strings though. But many things like adwords etc are passing variables in query strings for tracking purposes.

But for this particular page I would like to remove all query strings via mod_rewrite before the page loads so users on google chrome can still use the application.

Does anyone know how to remove all query strings from requests to a particular page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+ 
RewriteRule ^mothers-rings$ /mothers-rings? [R=301]
```