# htaccess remove all $_GET variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have hundreds of crawl errors to links like:

http://www.myfakebaseurl.com/education/imgcourse/Course.php?wikiinfa=1&page=5438

which i'd like to redirect to:

http://www.myfakebaseurl.com/education/courses.html

```
RewriteRule ^education/imgcourse/Course.php?(.*)$ http://wwww.myfakebaseurl.com/education/courses.html [R=301,L]
```

still results in:

```
http://www.myfakebaseurl.com/education/courses.html?wikiinfa=1&page=4973
```

How do i get rid of the all the $_GET variables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove all query strings from requests for particular page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543228/remove-all-query-strings-from-requests-for-particular-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new given query string will replace the old query string unless the `QSA` flag is given, so just give an empty query string.

```
RewriteRule ... http://example.com/foo.php? [L]
```